# Error Expression is non-assignable in AngularJS with checkbox and ng-model

Tags: angularjs

This is how my checkbox looks like:

```
<input type="checkbox"
       ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"
       ng-model="isSelected(row.data)" />
```

Everything works fine but in console I have an error: `[ngModel:nonassign] Expression 'isSelected(row.data)' is non-assignable.`

Perhaps because ng-model is 2-way binding. But I need `ng-model`, with `ng-checked` it doesn't work properly. `value="{{isSelected(row.data)}}"` also is not solution for me since is one way binding.

Any idea how to ride out this error?

Comment: See [AngularJS Error Reference - ngModel:nonassign
Non-Assignable Expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/nonassign).

Comment: instead of ng-model, why not use ng-change?

Answer (score 0):

Using `ng-checked` instead of `ng-model` might be more appropriate